# How to reorganize concatenated item in Excel?

Tags: excel

How to organize items like these in Excel?

```
COLUMN X - COLUMN Y

A  -   a; b; c; d

# into 

COLUMN X - COLUMN Y

A - a
A - b
A - c
A - d
```

What code do I have to use to do this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Please consider taking the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn what kind of questions that are typically asked (and anwered) here. SO is not a code-writing service where you request people to write code for you - if you want help, you should at least show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **X1** and **Y1**, in **Z1** enter:

```
=$X$1 & "  -  " &  TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(Y$1,"; ",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]